# How do I get the name of the backup file when using gitlab-backup?

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-22.04

**Our Setup:**

- Ubuntu 22.04 (hosted public vm)
- GitLab Community Edition v16.4.0

I'm attempting to create a script to backup our GitLab server. I was testing the `gitlab-backup` command and it created these files:

> /var/opt/gitlab/backups/1697128227_2023_10_12_16.4.0_gitlab_backup.tar
> /var/opt/gitlab/backups/1697142410_2023_10_12_16.4.0_gitlab_backup.tar

I want to grab this filename in my script so that I can upload it to our ftp server. Is there a way to specify the complete name instead of the partial name or how would I grab this filename after this runs:

`gitlab-backup create`

I understand that I can run it like this:

`gitlab-backup create BACKUP=dump`

That would only be a partial naming, if I understand it correctly. That would mean the name is dynamic with the date in the filename.

`[TIMESTAMP]_gitlab_backup.tar`

Thanks for the help!